# "Get + prep." vs. "go/come + prep."

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

The 4th definition for "[get](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get)" in macmillan:

> 4 [intransitive] to move to or from a position or place
>
> > get down: Abby had climbed a tree and couldn’t **get down**.
> >
> > get in/into: Dad stopped the car and told me to **get in**.
> >     She forgot her keys and **got into** the house through the window.
> >
> > get off: The hill was so steep we had to **get off** and push our bikes.
> >
> > get out: A car stopped and two men **got out**.

I was told that **get + prep.** implies difficulty or effort while **come/go + prep.** does not.

I was wondering if these "get/got" could be substituted for "come/came" or "go/went" without considerable change in meaning.

Comment: I have never heard that *get + preposition* implies difficulty.  "Get in the car" or "I got off the plane" is perfectly standard American English that implies nothing about difficulty.

Comment: What about "get across the river" or "get through the tunnel"? @stangdon

Comment: Not really.  For example, "We'll get lunch after we get across the river" is normal and does not imply difficulty.  _Get + preposition_ is part of many prepositional phrases, and some of those phrases may imply difficulty, but _get + preposition_ by itself does not.

Comment: Is it possible to be more specific about which prepositions? Because the choice makes a *huge* difference semantically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't sense a connotation of difficulty or effort in **get + *prep***. **Get** gets used in many, many phrasal verbs, where its core meaning of "acquire" mostly gets out of the way and serves as a placeholder for something else. There is often a connotation of acquiring the result in some irregular, direct, crude way, though. For example, **get out** means to exit, but **exit** suggests leaving in an orderly manner, such as through a door, whereas **get out** just means to get yerself out of the location somehow or other. **Get in** means to enter, but you don't "enter trouble", you "get in trouble".

The word **come** usually holds onto its core meaning, so it often suggests motion, or orderly motion, more strongly than **get**. But there is no rule. Whenever someone tells you a rule like that, tell them to "get off their high horse". :) English phrasal verbs work mainly by extending and varying familiar precedents in higgledy-piggledy fashion, not by orderly rules.

Below is some messy native-speaker reporting on the kind of stuff that you can't find in dictionaries and that can only be learned from experience, not from explicit statements.

---

> Abby had climbed a tree and couldn't **get down**.
>
> Abby had climbed a tree and couldn't **come down**.

**Come down** has a slight suggestion of smoother, more orderly motion. **Get down** means to move yourself down by any means or in any manner at all.

---

> Dad stopped the car and told me to **get in**.
>
> Dad stopped the car and told me to **come in**.

You don't ordinarily "come in" a car (except, uh, in [this sense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49055/6700)). In the right context, it works, though, such as if you knocked on the door of the car; then the situation is similar to knocking on the door of a room, where the normal response is "Come in." Another situation is if the story is being told from the perspective of someone inside the car: "Dad opened the passenger door and Kinzle came in and joined us." I'm sure you could "go in" a car in the right context, too. Very formally, I suppose you could "enter" a car, but I've never heard that. But ordinarily, you "get in" a car. That's nearly always what one says (at least in the United States).

---

> She forgot her keys and **got into** the house through the window.
>
> She forgot her keys and **came into** the house through the window.
>
> She forgot her keys and **went into** the house through the window.

These all mean pretty much the same thing. **Got into** has more of a connotation of doing things in an irregular, nonstandard way. **Came into** makes me imagine seeing her enter the house from a point of view inside the house. **Went into** makes me imagine seeing her enter the house from a point of view outside the house. **Got into** doesn't suggest any perspective.

---

> The hill was so steep we had to **get off** and push our bikes.
>
> The hill was so steep we had to **come off** and push our bikes.

I suppose it's possible to say **come off your bike** but that would be very unusual. It would suggest getting off your bike in order to come to some other point, suggested by context. For example, if I said "Come off your bike!" I would probably mean to get off your bike and come to me. Normally you just "get off" a bike. The only real synonym I can think of is "dismount", which is extremely formal.

By the way, because **get off** is so ambiguous (you could also "get off a hill"), you would normally word it this way:

> The hill was so steep we had to **get off our bikes** and push.

---

> A car stopped and two men **got out**.
>
> A car stopped and two men **came out**.

These mean almost the same thing. There is indeed a slight connotation of orderliness in the **came out** sentence, which the **got out** sentence lacks. I also find myself imagining the men as seen from the outside of the car with **came out**—or rather, imagining it more clearly than with **got out**.

Comment: You can, though, use "come down off" -- "Come down off your high horse" also works! But I think that requires two prepositions: go/come [direction] [on/onto/off]? "Come up onto the branch!" "Go left onto third street." ((Would I be wrong in thinking that "got [preposition]" tends to include the elided [my/him/her/ self]? E.g., Get yourself off the bike, got himself into the car, got themselves onto the plane...

Comment: @A.Beth I never thought about it before, but that (the elided getter) sounds right to me (or "ellipted getter", not that I would ever say that). The analogy with "acquire" holds good: "Acquire a bicycle" means "You—acquire a bicycle for yourself." But "get" allows much more flexibility: "Get him a bicycle" means "You—get a bicycle—for him." And "Get him out of here!" means "You—obtain for _him_ a change of location!" (Of course, you'd never say that with "acquire" or "obtain", and the metaphor is dead.)

Answer (score 2):

While **get + *prep*** does not imply difficulty or effort it is often more compatible with difficulty or effort than  **go + *prep***.  If I ask someone at school "Can you get home?" I suggest transportation could be a problem and I might be able to help.  If I ask "Can you go home?" I am asking whether they are free to leave -- or asking them to leave.

A child playing in the country might "find a way to get across the creek."  That refers to the physical challenge of crossing.  But "finding a way to go across the creek" sounds odd unless I make up some context.  Maybe the child is not allowed to cross and finds a pretext, or maybe the child can easily get across but wants to find the best way.