# What's the difference between "I have to get to" and "I have to go to"?

Tags: verb-usage

I know when to use them however I can't really explain why. Will you help me?

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of "**get to** *someplace*" is to *reach* that place.  Compared to that, "**go to** *someplace*" emphasizes the *progress*, the *movement toward*, rather than *reaching* it.

If you say

> I need to **go to** the meeting now.

you essentially state that you need to *leave* your current location.

If you say

> I need to **get to** the meeting now.

you state that it's time for you to *be at* the place where the meeting is held.

Comment: Colloquially, _get_ is sometimes used to imply there might be a challenge or difficulty in reaching the destination, too.  Compare the examples in this [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49154/22894): "Can you get home?" vs. "Can you go home?"

Comment: @JohnB : Sure. But it's not the "get" that implies the difficulty.  You can just as well imply it with "reach", like you did. Whereas with "go" there can be an implied difficulty in *leaving* the present location.

Comment: I agree that context is necessary to understand what might have been implied.

Comment: I think you're mistaken there, Victor. With no other context, I suggest virtually all native speakers would agree that one of the main potential differences in nuance between *I'll **go** to school tomorrow* and *I'll **get** to school tomorrow* is that the latter can often imply ***overcoming difficulty***.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence would mean you need to reach a place, an event, or a person. The second one means that that you have to leave, but not necessarily have to go somewhere else. Therefore, you can use the first sentence when you need to go somewhere else, and the second one when you have to leave your current location.

Answer (score 0):

**Get to** may imply some sort of urgency, or that there's difficulty in reaching a certain place.

**Go to** implies that you need to leave the place and continue the progress towards the destination (if there's any progress at all).